# Does Debian system uses FreeBSD kernel and Redhat system uses GNU kernel?

Tags: gnu, redhat, debian-based

Is it true that the Debian system uses FreeBSD kernel and the Redhat system uses GNU kernel. Does it make any difference to use Free BSD kernel or GNU kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the comment grew too long so I might as well post an answer. It is quite unclear what you are asking for, since you don't present any specific problem. At first glance this question does not belong to SO. But I assume since posted here you ask about difference from coders point of view.

1st to clear up, the BSD kernel is rather the alternative one like Hurd, so a Debian system can use FreeBSD kernel, it's not default. Actually its status is "official port".

Probably the biggest difference lies in the philosophy the user believes and their peace of mind, alternatively the hood they grew up in. Unless you are a distro developer or work even lower on the system.

Generally as a programmer you work with standard library implementation (libc,libc++,libstdc++ or whatever), they need to follow the standard, and the differences are really small. On debian this is natively provided with gnu toolset. You can assume to work in gnu wonderland. The kernel lies even lower, and you would need to work on really low-level kernel related stuff to notice difference of the kernel itself. Usually you work few layers from it and kernel should pleasantly abstract.

So no need to worry unless you acutally run into trouble.